# Prevent plot window from being created - Pyqtgraph plot

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm creating a dictionary of pyqtgraph.plot() items, and then later adding those items to a tabbed PyQt window. However, as soon as these objects are created, a window is generated as well. I'm able to call the win.hide() function to get rid of these windows, but they still pop up initially. Is there any way to prevent the window from popping up upon creation of the plot objects?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
#Generate dictionary containing pyqtgraph plots
plot_dict = {'plot_1': pg.plot(),
             'plot_2': pg.plot(),
             'plot_3': [pg.plot()'
              }
#Hide plot windows after they are generated
for plot in plot_dict:
    plot.win.hide()
```

Basically: is there a flag I can include with pg.plot() that prevents the windows from ever showing?

Comment: `'plot_3': [pg.plot()'` should be `'plot_3': pg.plot()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot()` is just a helper function that shows `PlotWindow`s. (see [plot](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph.html#plot)).
`PlotWindow` is a class that inherits from `PlotWidget` and shows itself in a window. (It also calls `show()` and does some other stuff like setting the title and resizing).
Both of these create the `QApplication` if it does not exist with `mkQApp()`.

fyi:

```
class PlotWindow(PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self, title=None, **kargs):
        mkQApp()
        self.win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        PlotWidget.__init__(self, **kargs)
        self.win.setCentralWidget(self)
        for m in ['resize']:
            setattr(self, m, getattr(self.win, m))
        if title is not None:
            self.win.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.win.show()
```

and

```
def mkQApp():
    global QAPP
    inst = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if inst is None:
        QAPP = QtGui.QApplication([])
    else:
        QAPP = inst
    return QAPP
```

So the solution is to use `PlotWidget` directly and call `show()` yourself when you want to see it. You also have to create the `QApplication` yourself.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = pg.mkQApp()

    plot_dict = {'plot_1': pg.PlotWidget(),
             'plot_2': pg.PlotWidget(),
             'plot_3': pg.PlotWidget()
              }

    plot_dict['plot_1'].show() # manually call show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation- that definitely clears up my confusion!